# INSERT stored procedure (PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, insert

I'm new to PL/SQL and stored procedures in general. I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will be executed from a Java program via a CallableStatement. The procedure takes two parameters, gets the id of the last record, increments it and inserts a new record with the newly incremented id. I found some examples online which are largely doing the same thing, but I can't resolve the errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertEmployeeProcedure
(lastname IN VARCHAR, firstname IN VARCHAR) AS
BEGIN
    lastEmpId NUMBER := SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO lastEmpId 
    FROM Employees;

    INSERT INTO Employees(id, lname, fname) VALUES(lastEmpId + 1, lastname, firstname);
END insertEmployeeProcedure;
/
```

The errors are:

```
Executed successfully in 0.018 s, 0 rows affected.
Line 1, column 1
Error code 984, SQL state 42000: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
Line 8, column 5
Error code 900, SQL state 42000: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Line 9, column 1
Error code 0, SQL state null: java.lang.NullPointerException
Line 9, column 1
Execution finished after 0.018 s, 3 error(s) occurred.
```

As far as I understand a store procedure is a mix of PL and SQL.That said, I tried incrementing lastEmpId (as lastEmpId := lastEmpId + 1) but got an "Invalid SQL statement" error. 
Also, Oracle docs (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm#CIHBCBHC) do not do a good job explaining how to define and use local variables in stored procedures.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: even if ignoring the fact that you are not using a sequence here - it's much better to execute `select max(id) from ...` and not `count(*)` because oracle can use min/max scan and obtain the max id with just two (or three) CR from the index.

Comment: varchar2 is the more common datatype -- Oracle discourages use of varchar. Also object names are case insensitive in Oracle unless you use double-quotes (which most practitioners would not) and the word "procedure" is redundant, so a more conventional name for the procedure would be insert_employee.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertEmployeeProcedure
(lastname IN VARCHAR, firstname IN VARCHAR) AS 

   lastEmpId NUMBER;
 BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO lastEmpId 
    FROM Employees;

    INSERT INTO Employees(id, lname, fname) VALUES(lastEmpId + 1, lastname, firstname); 
 END insertEmployeeProcedure; 
 /
```

Note that the variable is declared before BEGIN section.

Also, if you use SQL developer, after you execute package creation code run

```
 show errors
```

It will show you any problem before you actually call the procedure.

Comment: Moved the variable in the declare block. Thank you. Still getting "column not allowed here" in the INSERT line. Seems like proper SQL to me.

Comment: I'm connected to the database and running commands from NetBeans IDE. Will try SQL dev.

Comment: Downloading SQL dev. Taking awhile.

Comment: I've tried running the proc from SQL dev and everything does work fine - records are inserted. Must be an IDE issue. Will try to investigate later. Thank you so much for your help!:)

Answer (score 2):

You must use sequences to increment id column. Not always number of rows matches last used id

An example to create sequences:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;
```

An example of how to use this sequence follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertEmployeeProcedure
(lastname IN VARCHAR, firstname IN VARCHAR) AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Employees(id, lname, fname) VALUES(sequence_name.nextval, lastname, firstname);
END insertEmployeeProcedure;
```

Comment: Tried this. Most errors are gone! The last line is still "invalid SQL" for some strange reason. Thank you.